# Are quotes needed when naming an educational course?

Tags: quotation-marks

Do I need quotation marks when naming an educational discipline?

For example:

> An analysis of the educational discipline "English Language for Professional Purposes" has been conducted.

Or is it correct without them?

> An analysis of the educational discipline English Language for Professional Purposes has been conducted.

Comment: Which is easier to construe?

Comment: Personally, I like with quotes more because then it's clearly seen where the name itself is. But I'd like to know how it's correct grammatically.

Comment: Italicising would also work.

Comment: Thank you. But in the article I have the whole abstract italicised, so I'll probably have to go with quotes.

Comment: Quotes or italics also tell the reader when the title ends. But if the abstract is all italics, doesn't that make it hard to read?

Comment: Unluckily, it's not me who made the demands on the font. I just wanted to check if there exist any certain rules on whether such concepts can or can't be put in quotes, but all I found on the Internet was just about italicising the name of the whole work and putting in quotes its smaller parts.

Comment: '... how it's correct grammatically' No. Grammaticality and correct punctuation are totally separate issues. 'Is it correct to use quotes here?' Yes. And a good idea (though note that some style guides / editors have different preferences).

Comment: If the rest is italicised, make that part *not* italicised.

Comment: Okay. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the discipline: if the discipline were 'mathematics', say, you do not need such quotes because everyone knows that mathematics is a discipline, but if it is some very specific, unfamiliar, and potentially confusingly named discipline then the use of quotes is a way of warning the reader that the words are being used in a special sense.

So, if you wrote "An analysis of making friends and influencing people has been concluded" the reader might not understand that you were referring to an academic discipline with that name. (I am not claiming that such a discipline exists, but all sorts of oddly named disciplines do exist).

But in the specific example quoted, the introductory words "...the educational discipline...' warn the reader that what follows might not be the same as the natural meaning of the words. So quotes are not necessary for removing possible ambiguity or misunderstanding.

But there are style guide issues here too. For all I know, in some institutions it may the custom always to denote academic disciplines by using quotes, or, equally, never to do so.

If there is a relevant style guide follow it, otherwise write in ways that minimise the scope for confusion or misunderstanding on the part of the reader.